# How to set/delete cross domain cookie?

Tags: python, ajax, cookies, werkzeug

I need to delete cookie on another domain (*controlled by me*) without reloading page and opening new window. I'm trying:

```
        var XHR = window.XDomainRequest || window.XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = new XHR();
        var url = another_domain_url_which_removes_cookie;
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send()
```

but still after hitting target url cookie remains. If I change code to:

```
        var url = another_domain_url_which_removes_cookie;
        window.open(url)
```

it all works OK.
Server code which removes cookie is the following (python/werkzeug):

```
response = Response({}, mimetype='application/json')
response.delete_cookie('cookie_name')
```

Do you guys have any idea how to make it work if this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try posting your request in a hidden iframe of your doc...

Html

```
<iframe style="display:none;" id="myiframe"/>
```

Js

```
$("#myiframe").src(url);
```